# Cross Reference 2 lists in Python 2.x

Tags: python, list

I am new to Python (using 2.6 and 2.7), but I have searched docs.Python.org and this site. I have found a similar question:
[Comparing lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382301/comparng-lists-in-python)

...But I want to cross-reference 2 lists of different sizes and unknown orders.
Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
>>> mammals = ["gorilla","cat","rat","chimpanzee","dog","beaver"]
>>> apes =  ["orangutan","chimpanzee","human","gorilla"]

# magic happens here

>>> print result # order doesn't matter
['chimpanzee', 'gorilla']
```

Giving a result of common entries.  Knowing Python it seems there would probably be a simple/elegant solution to such a simple problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list(set(mammals) & set(apes))
```

If you need the result to be a list, if you're okay leaving it as a set then just

```
set(mammals) & set(apes)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick (and elegant) solution.  This is even better.

Answer (score 1):

Use sets:

```
mammals = ["gorilla","cat","rat","chimpanzee","dog","beaver"]
apes =  ["orangutan","chimpanzee","human","gorilla"]
print set(mammals).intersection(apes)
```

prints

```
set(['gorilla', 'chimpanzee'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick (and elegant) solution.  Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect for the `set` built-in type.

Make the base list a set:

```
mammals = set(["gorilla","cat","rat","chimpanzee","dog","beaver"])
```

Then use the intersection function (the compared list doesn't have to be a set)

```
>>> mammals.intersection(["orangutan","chimpanzee","human","gorilla"])
set(['gorilla', 'chimpanzee'])
```

Comment: Thanks... After seeing these answers, I guess I should have figured this out from docs.Python.org